# Copy files 45days old, verify and then delete

Tags: powershell

Trying to get a script working that can copy files that are 45 days old to a new network location, verify they copied and then delete those files from the original location. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Cool, what do you have so far?

Comment: I'm very new to powershell, I've taken a course on it through pluralsight but beyond that its new to me. I was tasked to do this and after some research and finding several options close to what I was looking for, I found this site and thought it would be a good place to learn from and possibly contribute to going forward as I'll be using powershell more and more going forward. Thanks for your help!

Comment: **John:** *"I'm in need of a script"*.... shows no work.  Don't be like John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This will get all child items in a folder (Folders and Files) Get-ChildItem Recurse
2. Select Items older then 45 days  $_LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-45)
3. Move them to a new location  move-item -destination
4. Remove the old items  Remove-Item

   get-childitem -Path "C:\HERE" -Recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-45)} | move-item -destination "\D:\THERE" | Remove-Item

UPDATE 8/12/2017
Added Verify that the file was moved before delete. if(Test-Path $Destination$($_.Name))

```
$Source = "C:\Source\"
$Destination = "D:\Destination\"
get-childitem -Path "C:\Source\" -Recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-45)} | move-item -destination "D:\Destination\" -force | ForEach-Object{
    if(Test-Path $Destination$($_.Name)){
        Remove-Item $_ -Force
    }
}
```

UPDATE 8/14/2017
All in one line

```
get-childitem -Path "C:\Source\" -Recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-45)} | move-item -destination "D:\Destination\" -force | ForEach-Object{ if(Test-Path $Destination$($_.Name)){Remove-Item $_ -Force}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Please make sure to mark the answer as complete if it works for u

Comment: when I run this in powershell: 

get-childitem -Path "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\SQLSrv2k5.msi" -Recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-45)} | move-item -destination "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\test2" | Remove-Item 

where I'm selecting a particular file, it works perfectly copying it to the test2 folder and deleting it from the zTest folder. But if I put in just this:

get-childitem -Path "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\" -Recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-45)} | move-item -destination "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\test2" | Remove-Item

Comment: Then I get this error: move-item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At line:1 char:123
+ ... ddDays(-45)} | move-item -destination "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\test2" | Remove ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\SQLSrv2k5.msi:FileInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: and when I delete the folder test2, and run the script again, within the folder zTest, I get a file test2 with no file extension but is the same size as the file SQLSrv2k5.msi that was origially in zTest and that's all that's there.

Comment: You need to add the -force to Move-Item,
`move-item -destination "\\D:\THERE" -Force`

Comment: Thank you. so is  - Force used in place of | Remove-Item    ?

Comment: Ok I tried it both ways and it works after | Remove-Item. Thank you very much for you time and help ArcSet. Going to test this further but I think this will work.

Comment: ArcSet, one more question, is there something that can be added to the script that shows that the file(s) being copied is verified first in the new location, then once verified, it is deleted from its original location?

Comment: At that point your asking for a script not a one liner. CAn you mark answer correct?

Comment: Ok, I tried pasting the code above into powershell and got multiple errors so figuring it won't work that way, I created a .bat file and ran it and this was the errors I got:


C:\temp>$Source = "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\"
'$Source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\temp>$Destination = "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\test2"
'$Destination' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: C:\temp>get-childitem -Path $Source -Recurse   | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-45)}   | move-item -destination $Destination -force
'get-childitem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You cant run powershell in a bat file like that. What erros did you get when you ran it from powershell?

Comment: when I pasted it in the way I copied it from above, powershell broke it separated the lines of code..when I use the up arrow I can see the individual lines from the script but bottomline it didn't really do anything when I "ran" it. It just sat there as a cursor for a long time doing nothing. I had to ctrl - C it to "stop" it and then that's when I did the up arrows to see the code I'd copied there and saw how it'd been broken up.

Comment: I tried making it all one line but I probably didn't get the syntax right ( a space here or there probably makes the difference). I tried it a bunch of different ways but ended up with the errors you see above.

Comment: I also tried that condensed code in powershell:

$Source = "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\" $Destination = "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\test2" get-childitem -Path $Source -Recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-45)} | move-item -destination $Destination -force | ForEach-Object{if(Test-Path $Destination$($_.Name)){Remove-Item $_ -Force}}

and this is the error I get:

Comment: At line:1 char:40
+ $Source = "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest\" $Destination = "D:\RnDDepts\Dropbox\zTest ...
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~Unexpected token '$Destination' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:89
+ ... x\zTest\test2" get-childitem -Path $Source -Recurse | where-object {$_.LastWrite ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'get-childitem' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: made it one line for you

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thank you for you time and patience ArcSet!

Comment: Done. Thanks again ArcSet!

Comment: So that works great but the issue being pointed out to me is that the move-item command moves the file and deletes it from the original location before it verifies its been moved. Would the Copy-item command be more appropriate?

Comment: and just so you know, I've been researching this and robocopy looks to be another if not better way to do this so I'm going to work on that as I know robocopy pretty well. I left this marked as complete as your script does most of the job very well. I just have to make sure the file isn't deleted before its been verified its been moved to the new location. Thanks again for all of your help.